# An idiom meaning "The ideal form of something always seems perfect, but in reality it probably isn't"

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there such a thing?

I am thinking, specifically, of socio-economic systems whose theory looks fine and good—but usually turn out bad. Consider the scenario where someone, for example, is defending the implementation of a so called "benevolent dictatorship." (Where the appropriate response is: Yes, that would be nice, but could never happen—because, when actually implemented, a single person with all the power will not be benevolent.)

Comment: In theory, theory and practice are the same, in practice they're not. Or "it looks good on paper".

Comment: @DanBron Oh, those are both excellent. "It looks good on paper" is one that totally escaped me. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You might be able to find more options using hose as a starting point for a thesaurus, quote, or Google search.

Comment: Systems that are easily described and sound desirable (but don't actually work in practice) are often dismissed as ***simplistic***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use the magnificently descriptive phrase I first encountered in Jonathan Lethem's brilliant book *Girl In Landscape* – **"The map is not the territory."**

The line may look straight, but the road goes straight up the mountain, or there's a crevasse, or it was a computer approximation, or you die of a heart attack before you get there.

A masterpiece in six words; stunning.

It was coined by [Alford Korzybski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Korzybski).

Comment: Genius. Great suggestion.

Comment: I don't mean to rain on @Dan Bron's great suggestion (it's an engineering cliche – sounds like a physicist-kind-of-thing to say), but there's an element of snark in the "..on paper" phrasing, while I perceive more of a dispassionate cautionary note in the "..territory" formulation.

Comment: Ah-ha – the "..on paper" phrasing seems always to connote an error, while the "..territory" formulation might just mean that something's counterintuitive but not mistaken.